# Make post request from js to django rest framework

Tags: javascript, django-rest-framework, axios

I have a DFR api endpoint:

```
url = http://127.0.0.1:8000/x/y/
```

Url of the page running JS code: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/x/z/1/`
I have logged in as User1 in my browser.

POST request - from DRF browser api  - good.

GET request - from javascript - good.

POST request - from javascript  - 403 error.

So perhaps I dont know how to make an authenticated ajax request from JS. When I do the same request from browser api, may be the browser takes care of authentication.

My current js code:

```
axios({
    method: 'post',
    baseURL: window.location.origin,
    url: '/x/y/',
// adding auth header also gives same 403 error for post request
// headers: {
//     Authorization: 'Token e77b8ca898b51cde72dcf2aa2c385942d771e972'
// },
    data: {
        name: 'xyz'
    },
    responseType: 'json',
})
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log(' success');
    })

    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(' error=', error.message);
    });
```

Comment: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/x/z/1/`

Comment: Check your browser's _Network_ console to make sure the request is actually going to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/x/y/`. Are you sure it's meant to have a trailing slash? Typically, I would expect the resource to be `/x/y`, not `/x/y/`

Comment: I tried the post request without end slash. Got following error - `RuntimeError: You called this URL via POST, but the URL doesn't end in a slash and you have APPEND_SLASH set. Django can't redirect to the slash URL while maintaining POST data.`

Comment: Right, ignore that then. I've never used Django so didn't know that was a thing. Check your _Network_ console though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on chrome browser, go in console `ctrl+shift+j` and then go in network. 
When a post request is made, we can see the error message in this network tab. 
My post request had following error:

```
"CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect."
```

To add csrf token on axios ajax request put following lines of code at beginning of your js file:

```
axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = "X-CSRFTOKEN";
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you appending the CSRF token in your request,CSRF can cause 403 errors.Try appending csrf token in request headers

Comment: can you please provide an example on how I would send CSRF in my above mentioned JS code